# Using a fixed epsilon (using the sequence criterion to proof continuity of a partial function)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity, partial-functions

So, I have an Calculus 1 exam at uni coming up and am currently working through the topic "Continuity". I've been trying to do some proofs and a few weeks back in tutorial we had this exercise:

$$ f : (0,1] \cup \{ 2 \} \to \Bbb R $$

$$ x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in (0,1] \\ 5 & \text{if } x = 2\end{cases} $$

Now, by definition, $f$ is continous in point $x_0 \iff$ $\forall$ $x_n \in D:  \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x\implies \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)= f(x) = f(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)  $ .

We did it in two parts, but I'll just do the first, because the second is analogous.

What we did: Let $x_0 \in (0,1] $ and $ x_n \in D $ so that $ x_n \to x_0 $. (That's clear, of course.)

But the next step wasn't clear to me, even after I asked my tutor. " For $ \epsilon := \frac {1}{2} \exists n_0 \in \Bbb N :  \forall n \ge n_0 : |x_n-x| \le  \frac {1}{2} = \epsilon$. "

**Why can we use have a fixed value for $\epsilon $?**

My tutor said something about how the interval looks so it doesn't reach 2. (I think, it lies back a while) But I thought $\epsilon$ should be general and only $\gt 0$. I tried looking online, but I haven't seen this method we used in the tutorial anywhere. It works, but **why**?

Hopefully someone can enlighten me.

(Note: The steps that followed I understand; we adapt the intervals for the values $x$ can be in the chosen interval and finally, we come to the conclusion that $ 0 \lt x_n \le \frac {3}{2} $ and that the limit is 1 because $f$ is defined as 1 for the chosen interval. So $f$ is continuous in the interval.)

Comment: I don't quite understand your part (2)? What do you want to do?

Comment: Part 2 is to proof continuity in the isolated point x_0=2 where we used the same fixed epsilon. It's almost exactly the same, just for a specific x, but the question remains: why can we have a fixed value for epsilon?

Comment: I think we can use defition with epsilon-delta to prove $f$ is continuous at $x=2$, and I don't understand why we only choose one fix epsilon. In fact, $x=2$ is the isolated point of the domain, and every function defined on this domain is continuous at isolated points.

Comment: I provide my proof in the answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is proving the function is continuous on $D = (0,1] \cup \{2\}$.

Now, by definition you provide, $f$ is continuous on $D$ if and only if for each $x_0 \in D$, for a sequence $x_n$ in $D$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x_0$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0)$. It is easy to obtain when $x_0 \in (0,1]$ as you proved.

To see why $f$ is continuous at $x=2$, take $\varepsilon > 0$ arbitrarily. Choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$. Then, for any $x \in D$, $|x-2| < \delta$, we have $x = 2$, and $|f(x)-f(2)| = 0 < \varepsilon$. Hence, $f$ is continous at $x=2$.

In fact, you can do the same argument to prove the function is continuous on the isolated points.

**Update:** Now we can use sequence criterion to prove $f$ is continous at $x_0=2$. Suppose $x_n$ converges to $x_0 = 2$.

By definition of convergent sequence, $x_n$ converges to $x_0$ if and only if for all $\delta > 0$, there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$, for all $n \ge n_0$. Note that it holds for all $\delta$. Because we have had $x_n$ converges to 2, so we can pick one $\delta$. Here we shall pick $\delta = 1/2$ (Why? It will become clearly in the next argument).

Now, let $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $n \ge n_0$. Then for all $x_n \in D$, $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$, we have $x_n = 2$. Here you can do same argument in the first proof to show $f_n$ converges to $f(2)$.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time for my problem and it also makes sense, but it sadly doesn't really answer my question concerning the use of a fixed epsilon. 
I'm trying to be somewhat well-versed in multiple methods to proved continuity, but am failing terribly. Thus I'm trying to use the sequence criterion too, not just the epsilon-delta one. But still, thanks.

Comment: Now I understand your question. We want to use sequence criterion to prove in part 2. In part 2, we then use definition of convergence sequence to prove. Now, note that we suppose $x_n$ converges to $x$. What will happen next with epsilon?

Comment: I update my answer. I think they want you to prove $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ by definition. In fact, is is similar to the proof sequence criterion is equivalent to definition of continuity by epsilon-delta.